# Solve the ODE $y'(x)^2=c^2y(x)^2-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm asked to show that the solution to the  ODE $$y'(x)^2=c^2y(x)^2-1$$ with initial conditions given by $r=y(-a)=y(a)$ is $$y(x)=\frac{1}{c}\cosh(cx)$$ where $cr=\cosh(ca)$.

**This is what I have so far:**

\begin{align*} &y'(x)=(c^2y(x)^2-1)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\& \implies \int (c^2y(x)^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \, dx = \int \, dx \\& \implies \operatorname{arccosh}(cy(x))=c(x+A) \\ &\implies y(x)=\frac{1}{c}\cosh(c(x+A)) \end{align*}

for some constant $A$.

Applying the initial conditions then gives me that $cr=\cosh(c(-a+A))$ and $cr=\cosh(c(a+A))$.

I'm not sure what to do from this point though. Do I need to somehow use that $\cosh(x)$ is an even function?

Comment: Are you sure about the solution? I mean, you write $y$ in the title but you integrate with $y^2$

Comment: not that $$y(x)=\frac{1}{c^2}$$ is also a solution if $c\ne 0$

Comment: @RafaBudría Sorry about that, I meant to write $y^2$. I've edited this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ODE you solved is $(y')^2=c^2y^2-1$

Rather, you are asking for the compatibility or not of the initial conditions, because the fact that $cr=\cosh(ca)$ is only possible with $A=0$

And they are compatible. The trick to see it is that you pointed, the fact it's even, plus that it's injective in $[0,\infty)$ and in $[0,-\infty)$.

$\cosh(x)=\cosh(-x)$ So,

$$\begin{cases}
   \cosh(c(a+A))=\cosh(c(-a-A))\;\text{because it's even}\\
   \cosh(c(a+A))=\cosh(c(-a+A))\;\text{by hypothesis}
\end{cases}$$

$c(-a-A)$ and $(-a+A)$ have to be both positive or both negative. And because injective $c(-a-A)=c(-a+A);\;2cA=0$ then $A=0$

Answer (score 1):

$$ (y')^2=c^2y^2-1$$

Differentiate and simplify

$$  \frac{y^{''}}{y}=c^2$$

For an even solution asked with simplest BC is composed only of $\cosh $ and no $ \sinh $ functions associated with $A$  leaving you with (classic catenary form)

$$ y = c\, \cosh \frac{x}{c}$$